# Content Search Webpart is not displaying after adding ddl.ClearSelection()

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, html, front-end, c-sharp

I'm having issue on asp:dropdownlist and search result display. One of the issues is "Cannot have multiple values on DropDownList", so, I looked it up and most of the suggestion were the use of ClearSelection method.

I added it and the error message was gone, however, the next issue is the search result was not displaying.

When I debugged the code, it was able to pull up the data and it was bounded to the datasource. I have also added try-catch to see if there any exception, however it passed the try block successfully.

Here is the code snippet for ddl.ClearSelection

```
try
        {
            this.ddlSearchBy.ClearSelection();
            this.ddlSearchBy.Items.FindByValue(csrSearchFormFilter.SearchBy).Selected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Then, here is code snippet for data binding and display:

```
public void Configure()
    {
        if (this.DataSource != null && this.DataSource.Count == 1)
        {
           //do code here
        }

        this.webpartSearchResults.DataSource = this.DataSource;
        this.webpartSearchResults.DataBind();
    }
```

Is the ClearSelection method can affect other webparts? If so, is there a way to eliminate the error on DropDownList without affecting the search result?

Any insight is much appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

this forum is for SharePoint admin issues, as your issue is about SharePoint development, you can create a new thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) which is a development forum.

Comment: hello, thank you @Kally_SPWX i have transferred it to its proper forum.